# Cannot get TFTP server working on Ubuntu using xinetd

Tags: xinetd, tftp

I am trying to get a very simple `tftp` server working. I followed the guides at several websites, including [how-to-setup-tftp-on-ubuntu](http://icesquare.com/wordpress/how-to-setup-tftp-on-ubuntu/) and [installing-and-testing-tftpd-in-ubuntudebian](http://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/installing-and-testing-tftpd-in-ubuntudebian/), but I haven't been able to get a `tftp` server working.

The `xinetd` service is running (I know this because I do a `ps -A | grep xinetd` and see it), but I don't see `tftp` in `netstat -na | grep LIST | grep 69`. In other words, `xinetd` is running but I don't see the `tftp` server. I tried connecting to the server from my Windows `tftp` client but it failed, so I know for sure it's not running.

My `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` config file looks like this:

```
service tftp
{
    protocol = udp
    port = 69
    socket_type = dgram
    wait = yes
    user = nobody
    server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args = -s /tftpboot 
    disable = no
}
```

The `/tftpboot` is owned by `nobody:nogroup`, and mode to `777`.

I thought maybe it was a firewall issue but ufw says it is inactive. In case it matters, Ubuntu is running inside a VirtualBox VM with the ethernet adapter bridged (not NAT) to my home network.

I also tried directly running `/usr/sbin/in.tftpd` and used the `--foreground` option, but it closes right away.

Comment: FYI, It's probably closing quickly b/c in.tftpd is already using the port (69). Only one process can use the port at a time.

Comment: Can you connect to the tftp server locally? Try this cmd. on the tftp server: tftp 127.0.0.1 GET someimage

Comment: What is the output of using `strace` with it running in the foreground?

Comment: Once restart xinetd service and check `tail -20f /var/log/syslog`. if possible post on question

Comment: I was able to connect to it locally! The netstat -na | grep LIST | grep 69 is wrong because there is no LISTENING text in the netstat output for the tftp server. I ran sudo netstat -pa | grep xinet and saw the server on port 69. As for why Windows couldn't see it, I turned off the Windows firewall and it worked, so the damned Windows firewall was secretly blocking it!